# Show link destination with Vimperator

Tags: vimperator

Because I'm not too fond of surprises on the web, I'd like Vimperator to show me where a particular link on a website leads to. A URL would be nice.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`;;<number>` focuses the link and display its URI in the status bar instead of URI of currently opened page.

I am not sure about Vimperator exactly, but it works in its further development – [Pentadactyl](http://5digits.org/), so I guess, it should work in the former too. If does not, perhaps it’s a good occasion to consider switching to the Pentadactyl finally. :-)

Answer (score 4):

The **"showstatuslinks"** setting allows you to see the selected link (or any link you hover over with the mouse) just above the status bar. Set it to 3 like this:

:set ssli=3

Details:

> *'showstatuslinks' 'ssli' number(default: 1)* 
>    Possible values:
>
> - **0**    Don't show link destination
> - **1**    Show the link destination in the status line
> - **2**    Show the link destination in the command line
> - **3**    Show the link destination in the content area

Comment: Thank you for the post, it's really helpful. In my setting, Vimperator now ignores everything apart from the option 3 (but it used to be ok with the 1), it may be due to a lot of installed addons.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I currently do it:

```
;y
```

This numbers all the links on the current website, just like `f`.
When you choose a link, Vimperator yanks the URL of the website it leads to into the clipboard.

As a side-effect it shows the URL in Vimperator's toolbar at the bottom of Firefox (the "Liberator Statusline Toolbar" as it's called).

I'm using Vimperator 3.8.2.

I don't know if there's a more elegant way but I would very much like to hear it, if you have an idea.